# jQuery blur() function is not working in android native browser when showing the popup

Tags: jquery

In android native browser below code is not working

```
$('#address-success').on('shown', function () {  
    jQuery('input').blur();  
})
```

Any suggestions that would be great.

Comment: Try to alert inside shown function.$('#address-success').on('shown', function () {  alert('hello');
    jQuery('input').blur();  
})

Comment: what you are going to do with this

Comment: @Himabindu what you want to do this

Comment: After filling the form click on button i want to show the popup. But with that pop up the last input element is showing as focus and it is highlighting.  I placed alert it is going to the function but blur is not working in samsung tablet native browser.  In ipad , iphone5 and in other devices it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

If you want to do file blur event you need to use trigger

```
$('#address-success').on('shown', function () {  
    jQuery('input').trigger('blur');
})
```